# Ubuntu 12.04 not asking for password when resuming from hibernate

Tags: passwords, ubuntu-12.04, hibernate

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and when I hibernate and resume back, the system takes me directly to the desktop without any prompt for password.

I have uswsusp package installed  for hibernation/suspend. When I do a suspend and resume, the system is prompting for password.

I confirmed that the 'Require my password when waking from suspend' checkbox is checked under System Settings -> Brightness & Lock.

I would really appreciate if someone could guide me to a fix for this password issue on hibernation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[From AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/148691) - it's suggested to add the screensaver lock command:

> I've been able to workaround this issue, by using the following command
>
> `sudo pm-hibernate; gnome-screensaver-command -l`
>
> Do note that, you should **run this as a normal user** and not as root user for locking to work, because by default in Ubuntu, there is no password for the root user so after resume, lock-screen can be unlocked by simply shaking the mouse.

Answer (score -1):

Can't really tell what the issue is, but one thing that i can suggest is to remove the package that you had mentioned above and try again.